# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, insert, syntax-error

I am writing the following code in my C-Sharp Form Application and its giving me the following error.

```
> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.


OleDbCommand cmd =
    new OleDbCommand(
            "Insert into Info (username, password) Values ('"
          + username
          + "', '" 
          + password 
          + "')"
        , conn
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word PASSWORD is a reserved keyword.
To use it you should enclose the string in square brackets

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into Info (username, [password]) Values ('" + username + "', '" + password + "')", conn);
```

And please, please, do not use string concatenation to build sql statements. It is a very bad practice that leads to other syntax errors (username or password with single quotes) or worst to a sql injection Attacks. Take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) to what could happen if you have a smart and malicious user

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into Info (username, [password]) Values (?,?)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", password);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Can i also write Select command like this, oledbCommand cmd= new oledbcommand ("Select * from Table where id= ? and password= ?")

Comment: Yes of course, the concept is the same. The parameters should always used to pass user input text. You can't use a parameter to express the table's name or column's name though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bracket off `password`.  It's a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

```
OleDbCommand cmd = 
    new OleDbCommand("Insert into Info (username, [password]) Values ('" + username + "', '" + password + "')", conn);
```

Comment: @HansUp - thought it was username, but user is the reserved word.  Typed too quickly.  :)

Comment: Yeah, `username` *looks* suspicious.  :-)  And the brackets wouldn't hurt ... so including them wasn't a problem.  You earned +1 based on `[password]`.

Comment: @HansUp thanks!  Yes, the square brackets don't hurt (at least, I don't think they do).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's an illegal character (such as a single quote) within the username or password variables. Make sure they're sanitized.

Comment: That's a good point, but the better way to deal with that possibility is to use a parameter query as Steve suggested.